# Animate UIView grow/shrink

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I have a UILabel I want to animate growing and shrinking. While the size changes I need the bottom left corner to remain static so that it always appears directly above a bottom toolbar. I am using the following code to make the label grow:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{  
    CGFloat lblHeight = 42.0f;
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 
                CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds) - kBottomBarHeight - lblHeight, 
                CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.bounds), 
                lblHeight)];                
} completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
```

and to make it shrink I use the same logic except that lblHeight is set to 17.0f

The view correctly grows but when I try to shrink it the frame change animation is not animated. It blips into the new size and then animates into the new origin/location. I need the frame change to be animated. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering I've managed to get the desired behavior by doing the following.

In the expand method, I use the UIView animation to alter the frame.
In the shrink method, I use the UIView animation to alter the bounds and center.

I'm a little baffled as to why this works but trying to shrink with the frame does not. If anyone can share some insight into this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should not really use frames to animate, rather you should use the transform property of your label.

However, since you want one corner to remain static, I think its best you use Core Animation. `CALayer` has a property called `anchorPoint` that determines which point a layer will rotate with respect to, and I'm pretty sure it is also valid for grow/shrink effects.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this answer.  1) Frame _is_ a perfectly good animateable property 2) `+animateWithDuration` is a Core Animation wrapper for a UIView, and 3) anchor point would only work if he were manipulating the underlying layer's properties.

Comment: @CodaFi Yes Frame is a perfectly animatable property but also I've seen a lot of instances where it caused problems or weird behavior. and I know that anchor point only affects the layer manipulations, so what I was suggesting was to get rid of animateWithDuration and use something like layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat sx,CGFloat sy,CGFloat sz);

Comment: Yes, but in eliminating `+ animateWithDuration`, he would lose animation.  And besides, he mentions specifically that he wishes to retain a corner of the view's position, and in using a MakeScale, he would shrink/grow from a center point.

Comment: No, if he sets: testLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);
    testLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(.5, .5, 1);

The layer will scale to half size but will have its left bottom corner fixed. In this case this is just a simple implicit animation. But the same result will hold for an explicit animation. Maybe he will lose the UIView animation method but he can use an explicit Core Animation for this case.

Comment: @Kaaan I tried your suggestion to use the transform property and there is a problem. If I set the transform like this: [label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 2)] the label does indeed grow like it needs too, but the text size also magnifies and becomes blurry. Do you know of a way to apply a transform to a UILabel without effecting the text?